# Hitting major dip in performance on mobile devices serving website, even when served locally

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, mobile, touch

Alright, I'm at the end of my tether with this one. I've hosted the site at: http://loudcolor.com/brands/yolancris.html if anybody's willing to lend a hand.

The website is very heavy on image content, and has extensive use of some js/jquery plugins to bolster the user experience, which of course ain't worth a damn thing if you can't even scroll the site!

I don't seem to have any issues on desktop versions of the site. Webkit and firefox seem to be working pretty consistently. Though, whenever I load the site up on a touch device (iPhone/iPad) whether via ghosting (wifi and Adobe Edge inspect) or over a server the performance lag is huge, the thing won't even scroll. I appreciate that the site is heavy on image size - but I'm using lazy loading extensively to shave a lot of that off. With the exception of the home page, no page exceeds an initial load of ~300k.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I've been banging my head against a wall till the early hours now. If you guys need any further resources or details just let me know. Thanks.

Kyle

Comment: For starters, you might want to decrease the size of your thumbnail images with an image editor, instead of having the browser resize them down for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else runs across a similar issue. The problems were the following:

• I had a container set to

```
    overflow: auto;
```

• Which combined with a:

```
    $(window).resize();
```

on a touch and scroll event ended up being a recipe for disaster - or in this case, really buggy scrolling on a touch device.

Hope this helps somebody. Happy coding ;)